# Get html body height after data load complete from AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe

Need to get height of html document (body) , after contents are loaded from some service using AngularJS.

```
 /* SHOW RECENT POSTS */
  app.controller('RecentPostsController', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http.get("/site/recentpostsjson/" + appname).success(function (data) {
        $scope.posts = data;

        /* HEIGHT FROM THIS IS COMING DEFAULT , NOT WHAT WE GET AFTER DATA 
           LOAD FROM ANGULAR JS */
        var contentHeight = window.document.body.scrollHeight;
        alert(contentHeight);           
    });
});
```

Comment: Try $('body').height();. It Should Work.

Comment: Nope, it does not work. Actually it get default height & i need height after data is loaded from server & being populated to html using angularJS

Comment: Try `$window.innerHeight`

Comment: Please understand the question , window.innerHeight gets default height , i need height when angular JS has finished rendering data to html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$scope.$apply() was the trick that helps in rendering the data & getting after height.

```
  /* SHOW RECENT POSTS */
   app.controller('RecentPostsController', function ($scope, $http) {
    var appname = getAppName();

    $http.get("/site/recentpostsjson/" + appname).success(function (data) {
        $scope.posts = data;
        $scope.$apply();
        /* NOW GET THE HEIGHT */
        alert(window.document.body.clientHeight);         
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this help

```
app.controller('RecentPostsController', function ($rootScope, $scope, $http) {

   $http.get("/site/recentpostsjson/" + appname).success(function (data) {
       $scope.posts = data;
       $rootScope.$broadcast('contentLoaded')
   });

});

app.directive('contentHeight', ['$timeout', '$rootScope', function($timeout, $rootScope){
    return {
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
              $rootScope.$on('contentLoaded', function(){
                  $timeout(function(){elem[0].scrollHeight});            
              })  
        }  
    } 
})
<body ng-app="someApp" content-height><!--All you staff --></body>
```

You must manipulate DOM only in directives!
P.S. timeout service run callback function only then digest is stopped

Without timeout http://jsfiddle.net/zcbzajqL/

Comment: Do you have simpler solution than this without using $timeout.

Comment: @Moniv I add jsfiddle without timeout and events

Comment: Actually $scope.$apply() was the trick that helps me in getting the after height.But yes your solution gave me the hint. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what kind of view you are trying to render, a large view takes more time to render, thus if you solely depends on $http request got resolved is not reliable. Because it might take additional digest cycle to render.

However, if you have `ngAnimate` in your module, you may use `$animate:before`, `$animate:after` or `$animate:close` to determine the right time to execute the correct callbacks.

Reference https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#features-24